# Vite + React: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, build, vite, build-error, vite-reactjs

[image: error during build: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]
I was building website with vite + react
However, when trying to compile the production build, I run in the following error:
error during build:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at String.substring ()
at replaceClose

Comment: This error means you have an infinite loop of calling functions.